# UITabBarController does not respond on iPhone 5 simulator: 4-inch retina display

Tags: ios

I have a UITabBarController that displays four options. These have all worked fine until now.

My problem is that the tab bar does not respond only when testing on the 4-inch retina display device in the IOS Simulator. All other devices the tab bar responds and I am able to select other views.

I don't have an iPhone 5 to test it on so I don't know if this is a fault with the simulator or Apple have changed the workings of tab bars etc for the new hardware or made it stricter and I wrote the wrong code in the first place.

Comment: I had the same issue with iOS 6.1 simulator and 4-inch retina display. Given [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12699387/956397) works!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I had this issue as well and this worked for me:

Go to the MainWindow.xib, select the Window object and check the "Full Screen at Launch".

Comment: I don't have MainWindow.xib. how I can solve this issue. please help me.

Comment: Saved me a lot of hair pulling

Comment: hi! I have the same problem. but what if I don't have a MainWindow.xib??

Comment: Thank you for saving me at least a couple hours of time. :D

Comment: I know there are already a lot of thank yous on here, but I need to add another one.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 16):

In your main window, select the "Full Screen at Launch" option. Here's an image:

[image]

Comment: Hey what tool did you use to draw the arrows & numbers on a screenshot?

Comment: @TurbZ It is indeed. I'd recommend the older version. I'm using 1.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

Could there possibly be a transparent view over the top of it? The change in view size might be positioning something in the wrong place.