# iPhone 5 TabBar not working after adding Default-568h@2x.png

Tags: iphone, ios6, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone 5 TabBar not functioning in proper position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569189/iphone-5-tabbar-not-functioning-in-proper-position)

I added the magic Default-568h.png to my project and my App resized itself. So far so good. But: My UITabBar is not working anymore. It's delegate is not called. I first thought it is covered by another view but it isn't. The Delegate is there and it's all working on my "old" iPhone 4. Any ideas?

Comment: Set Window to Full Size At Launch in the XIB. Worked for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543567/uitabbarcontroller-does-not-respond-on-iphone-5-simulator-4-inch-retina-display

Comment: Yes, "Full Screen at Launch" is the medicine (:

Comment: @TihomirSimeonov - you should make that an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1) You need to go to your main xib, click on the window object, and set the "Full Size at Launch" property.

2) If you are converting an older project, you also have to make sure that your window rootcontroller is set to the tabbarcontroller. You can do that by dragging in Interface builder or programatically in your application applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

Comment: 2) Is related to autosynthesis and not to unclickable Tab Bar, though. I know this because I just updated an app written in an older Xcode (I got the warning for the tab bar rootVC) and the Tab Bar worked after step 1.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure the "Full Screen at Launch" option is checked for your main window. Head to Interface Builder and follow the 1, 2, 3 below.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Define a height of the TabBar.

Comment: The TabBar has a frame of 0, 0, 320, 49