# iPhone 5 Applications (4 inch Screen)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

I'm (still) trying to convert one of my iPhone applications to iPhone 5, but it still looks like this in the simulator...

What am i doing and why won't it fill up the entire screen?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you provided a 4" sized launch image? That's the indicator that tells the OS that your application supports the full screen.

Comment: In a similar vein, simply converting an old project to use image xcassets files did the trick - it probably cues the app in a similar manner.

Answer (score 3):

Have you selected in your UIView attributes inspector in XCode iPhone 5 screen size?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the url,
[iPhone 5 TabBar not functioning in proper position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569189/iphone-5-tabbar-not-functioning-in-proper-position)

Now, in xib, at the right side, under 'Interface Builder Document', put a tick-mark on **use autolayout** and fix your objects in xib accordinlgy.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install Xcode 4.5 GM. Set a 4-inch launch image for
   your app. This is how you get 1136px screen height (without it, you
   will get 960px with black margins on top and bottom).
2. Test your app, and hopefully do nothing else, since everything should work magically if you had set auto resizing masks properly. If you didn't, adjust your view layouts with proper auto resizing masks or look into Auto Layout if you only want to support iOS 6 going forward.

Also note: The auto-rotation API has changed completely, take a look at that as well if your application supports any rotation other than default.